# Routing for One to Many Relationship in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having two Controllers

1)ServerController

2)ClientController

Both of These are having actions

ServerList,ClientList

AddServer,AddClient

DeleteServer,DeleteClient

and I want to follow rest principle so urls should be like this

http://mydomain/Server/ServerList which will display all server list

Now for Specific serverid there can be so many clients so url should be
http://mydomain/Server/serverid(say:1)/Client/ClientList which will display all client list for serverid 1

http://mydomain/Server/Add which will add a Server

Same for Client....

http://mydomain//Server/id/Delete which will delete server for id

Same delete for client.....

Please tell me How should I Write Routes for This,
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing this situation I really found these things

1)According to rest principle these urls will be like this

server/addserver,server/serverid/addclient
//to add server and addclient(to add specific client for that server)

server/serverlist,server/serverid/clientlist
//displaying serverlist and clientlist(for a specific serverid display all clientlist)

server/serverid/deleteserver,server/serverid/client
//deletes server and client(for a specific serverid delete all clients)

and i'm glad to say guys that everthing was under a single route

```
         routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Server",id=UrlParameter.Optional ,action = "ServerList" );// Default parameters which will redirect us to ServerList.
```

That was the solution I was looking for.
Thanks